# XSLT stylesheet not showing values

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am trying to transform an XML source to a HTML page using a XSLT stylesheet.

The XML code is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="P_44.xsl"?>
<JournalData>
<PatientData><Patient><Name>Jones, John</Name>
<CodeNumber>191212121212</CodeNumber>
<CodeNumberType>C</CodeNumberType>
<BirthDate>1912-12-12</BirthDate>
<Sex>F</Sex>
<Deceased>0</Deceased>
<DoubleReg>0</DoubleReg>
<InterpreterNeeded>0</InterpreterNeeded>
</Patient>
</PatientData>
</JournalData>
```

The XSLT stylesheet is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<h1>Journal</h1>
<table border="1">
<tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
<th>Element name</th>
<th>Contence</th>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#FBF5A4">
<th>Patient</th>
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="JournalData/PatientData/Patient/Name">
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="local-name()" /></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="Name" /></td>
</tr>  
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:for-each select="JournalData/PatientData/Patient/CodeNumber">
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="local-name()" /></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="CodeNumber" /></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:for-each select="JournalData/PatientData/Patient/CodeNumberType">
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="local-name()" /></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="CodeNumberType" /></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:for-each select="JournalData/PatientData/Patient/BirthDate">
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="local-name()" /></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="BirthDate" /></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:for-each select="JournalData/PatientData/Patient/Sex">
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="local-name()" /></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="Sex" /></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:for-each select="JournalData/PatientData/Patient/Deceased">
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="local-name()" /></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="Deceased" /></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:for-each select="JournalData/PatientData/Patient/DoubleReg">
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="local-name()" /></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="DoubleReg" /></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:for-each select="JournalData/PatientData/Patient/InterpreterNeeded">
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="local-name()" /></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="InterpreterNeeded" /></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table> 
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This transform to a nice two column HTML table where the first one has the element name printed out, but the second column is blank. Why aren't the values displayed? What is wrong in the stylesheet?

---

Thank you so much both of you. I got it working now. The columns continue downwards now with a new title on yellow background (just like "Patient") called "PatientAddress". It is one step further nesting:

becomes

It all works fine just for one annoying detail. Since the element name "PatientAdress" is a child under "Patient" it becomes double printed. First when all children (is that the right terminology?) under "Patient" are printed all values under "PatientAdress" comes in one line, and then again when I set

How do I get rid of the first instance? Looking like this:

PatientAddress  Bondstreet 9 211 11 Mersey Surrey 12 Surrey 72

Should only look like this:

```
<tr bgcolor="#FBF5A4"><th>PatientAddress</th></tr><tr><td>Address1</td>   <td>Bondstreet 9</td></tr><tr><td>ZipCode</td><td>211 11</td></tr><tr><td>City</td><td>Mersey</td></tr><tr><td>State</td><td>Surrey</td></tr><tr><td>StateCode</td><td>12</td></tr><tr><td>District</td><td>Surrey</td></tr><tr><td>DistrictCode</td><td>72</td></tr></tbody></table></body></html>
```

(Trying to paste a nice looking table, but not succeeding....:-()

Comment: Out of the 8 questions you've asked over the last three years, you've accepted 0 answers.  Accepting an answer helps future readers by indicating that the answer worked for you.  It also increases the asker's and answer's reputation, reflecting their helpfulness over time.  Read how to accept and more about accepting [**here**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) and please consider accepting an answer to his question and to your past questions too. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Inside of the `for-each` you need to simply use `<xsl:value-of select="."/>` to output the string value of the context node. If you use the `<xsl:value-of select="foo"/>` then you look for a child element of that name of the context node.

Answer (score 0):

**Just iterate once over each `Patient` and once over each child of `Patient`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h1>Journal</h1>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Element name</th>
            <th>Contence</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="JournalData/PatientData/Patient">
            <tr bgcolor="#FBF5A4">
              <th>Patient</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="*">
              <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>
              </tr>  
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table> 
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then the XSLT will style your XML like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it working now. The columns continue downwards now with a new title on yellow background (just like "Patient") called "PatientAddress". It is one step further nesting:                                                                                                     <xsl:for-each select="JournalData/PatientData/Patient">           becomes                                                                                                   <xsl:for-each select="JournalData/PatientData/Patient/PatientAddress">

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that inside your `<xsl:for-each>` elements, you are already matching the element that you want. For example:

```
<xsl:for-each select="JournalData/PatientData/Patient/Name">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="local-name()" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Name" /></td>
    </tr>  
</xsl:for-each>
```

Here, you have matched Name already in `<xsl:for-each>`, so in `<xsl:value-of select="Name" />` you are actually trying to find the value of the Name child of Name. And there isn't one. You should simply use `<xsl:value-of select="."/>` to get the value of the element you are at.

Rather then replace all such lines in your template, you could do it once as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h1>Journal</h1>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th>Element name</th>
                        <th>Contence</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr bgcolor="#FBF5A4">
                        <th>Patient</th>
                    </tr>

                    <xsl:apply-templates select="//Patient/*"/>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Patient/*">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will get the desired results for the input you show here, but I don't know how you would want it to look for many Patient records.